# Cropping of free selection using mouse in a jpg picture in .Net Windows application (C#)

Tags: c#, .net

Requirement is to crop any shape from the .jpg image using mouse selection of the area. Rectangular shape selection for cropping provided in most software available.
But the requirement is not to limit to Rectangular but allow user to select any shape [free selection] and do the cropping.

Please suggest a software where this is possible and/or sample code to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. So if you are looking for software, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Why must it be in c#? Are you looking for ready-to-use software, or for a library? What other features must it have, or should it not have? Almost each image prog supports that.

Comment: Looking for a tool like Aspose or GdPicture. But for these both only support rectangular selection and cropping.

Comment: Asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. I e.g. haven't heard from either of the two. Am I assume correctly you are looking for a stand-alone too to do "free-hand" cropping (i.e. in any shape, like offered by Gimp with the lasso/rope selection feature)? And why must it be .net/c#?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract freehand region from an image using Leadtools. As a disclaimer, I work for LEAD Technologies that develops this toolkit. If you are displaying the image in an ImageViewer, you can use the ImageVeiwerAddRegionInteractiveMode to allow the user to select a region with their mouse. You can then copy the region to a second imageViewer using the following code, which is set in the WinForms Form constructor:

```
var regionInteractiveMode = new ImageViewerAddRegionInteractiveMode
{
    Shape = ImageViewerRubberBandShape.Freehand,
};

regionInteractiveMode.WorkCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (imageViewer.Floater != null)
    {
        imageViewer2.Image = imageViewer.Floater.Clone();
        imageViewer.Floater.MakeRegionEmpty();
        var region = imageViewer2.Image.GetRegion(null);
        imageViewer2.Image.MakeRegionEmpty();
        imageViewer2.Image.SetRegion(null, region, RasterRegionCombineMode.SetNot);
        new FillCommand(RasterColor.White).Run(imageViewer2.Image);
        imageViewer2.Image.MakeRegionEmpty();
    }
};

imageViewer.InteractiveModes.BeginUpdate();
imageViewer.InteractiveModes.Add(regionInteractiveMode);
imageViewer.InteractiveModes.EndUpdate();
```

You should get a result similar to this:
[image: Sample application]